# Why this example about pseudorandom generators is performed like that?

Tags: pseudo-random-generator

Suppose Alice wishes to authenticate herself to Bob, by proving she knows a secret that they share. With [pseudorandom number generators (PRNGs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) they could proceed as follows.

1. They both seed a PRNG with the shared secret $s$.
2. Bob picks sends Alice some random number $i \in \mathbb{N}$.
3. Alice proves she knows the share secret by responding with the $i$-th random number generated by the PRNG.

I am wondering why Bob sends a random number $i$ instead of just $1$. Then Alice just sends $G(s)$ (where $G(\cdot)$ is the PRNG) to Bob. Only Alice and Bob should have access to the secret $s$, and hence this should also work. In the above example, Alice and Bob should both have to compute $G(s)$ $i$ times, making it much more inefficient.

Which is the difference between what I am proposing and the original example? Aren't them both equally secure?

Comment: Where is this scheme suggested? As it's not on the linked Wiki page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bob sends random number so they can use their shared secret for authentication process many times.

Comment: Ok, but it would be enough with my version for one-time use

Comment: Yes, it would but for one-time use you don't need prng. You can simply use the shared secret s.